# Using functions from classes

Tags: c++, class

I am learning C++ and very new at using classes, and I am getting very confused in trying to use them. I am trying to convert my existing code (which used structs) so that it uses classes - so while I know what I am trying to do I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

I was told that when using functions from the class, I first need to instantiate an object of the class. So what I have tried (a snippet) in my main function is:

```
int main()// line 1
{
    string message_fr_client = "test"; //line2

    msgInfo message_processed; //line 3
    message_processed.incMsgClass(message_fr_client); //line 4

    if (!message_processed.priority_check(qos_levels, message_processed)) //line 5
        cout << "failure: priority level out of bounds\n"; //line 6

    return 0; //line 7
}
```

Could you help me clarify if my following assumptions are correct? The compiler is not showing any error and so I don't know if it is error-free, or if there are ones lurking beneath.

1. At line 4, is the function `incMsgClass` being performed on the string `message_fr_client` and returning the resultant (and modified) `message_processed`?
2. At line 5, the function `priority_check` is being performed on the `message_processed` and returning a boolean?
3. In my class definition, I have a function `getPath` that is meant to modify the value of `nodePath` - is it just a matter of using `message_processed.getPath(/*arguments*/)`?

I haven't included the body of the functions because I know they work - I would just like to find out *how* the class functions interact. Please let me know if I can be clearer - just trying to clear up some confusion here.

Here is my class:

```
#ifndef clientMsgHandling_H
#define clientMsgHandling_H

#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

class msgInfo
{
public:
    msgInfo();
    msgInfo(int, int, int, std::string, std::list<int>);

    /*classifying message*/
    msgInfo incMsgClass(std::string original_msg);

    /*message error checks*/
    bool priority_check(int syst_priority, msgInfo msg); //check that message is within qos levels
    bool route_check(std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> route_table, msgInfo msg); //check that route exists

    void getPath(msgInfo msg, std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int> route_info, int max_hop);

private:
    int source_id;
    int dest_id;
    int priority;
    std::string payload;
    std::list<int> nodePath;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I'm sorry i can't accept multiple answers, but thank you all! - all bits and bobs help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may compile (and even run), there are a few oddities with the code as shown:-

First off, class methods know which object they are operating on - so your `priority_check` and `route_check` methods probably don't need `msgInfo` as a parameter.,

for example, your old non-class function might be like this

```
bool priority_check(int p, msgInfo msg)
{
  return msg.priority < p;
}
```

But the new one should look like this:

```
bool msgInfo::priority_check(int p)
{
  return priority < p;
}
```

Also, `incMsgClass` is a bit odd, as it's a non-static class method that returns a msgInfo object. It's difficult to tell without understanding what it's supposed to do, but it seems possible that this function should actually be a constructor, rather than  a regular method.

One other thing is that you're currently passing a msgInfo *by value* to those methods. So if the method needed to modify the passed msgInfo, it would not have any effect. It's generally better to pass objects by reference or const reference to other methods. So, back to the previous non-method example, it should really be this.

```
bool priority_check(int p, const msgInfo &msg)
...
```

But, as I said, you probably don't need the `msgInfo` parameters anyway.

Comment: just to clarify - I've just changed it to look like `bool msgInfo::priority_check(int p){}`, and does this mean that when I use `message_processed.priority_check(x)`, it will know to check that `message_processed` fulfils that criteria, which is why I don't have to pass it in as an argument?

Comment: Yes: 'under the hood', when a object's method is called a pointer to the object is passed as a kind of hidden parameter called `this`. So when you write `priority`, it's the same as `this->priority`. You're using `std::string`, so look at how things like `length()` are defined.

Answer (score 0):

> At line 4, is the function incMsgClass being performed on the string message_fr_client

Yes

> and returning the resultant (and modified) message_processed?

Whatever it's returning, you're ignoring the return value. It can modify the object itself, yes, because the function is not const.

> At line 5, the function priority_check is being performed on the message_processed and returning a boolean?

Yes

> In my class definition, I have a function getPath that is meant to modify the value of nodePath - is it just a matter of using message_processed.getPath(/*arguments*/)?

If a member function is intended to modify one of the class members, it's just a matter of not marking that function const

Comment: For point 1, if I did `message_processed = message_processed.incMsgClass(message_fr_client);` instead of the original, that would mean that `message_processed` has now been modified?

Comment: @SCCS: if incMsgClass actually modifies message_processed, then it's the same thing. The solution in your comment is just one copy less efficient

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without implementation-details, but here we go:

I. You are passing a `std::string` as value (C++ is call-by-value by default), so you get a copy of the `std::string` in your method. If you want to work on the object you passed and manipulate it, use a reference on the object, like

```
msgInfo incMsgClass(std::string& original_msg); // notice the ampersand
```

then you can change your signature to

```
void incMsgClass(std::string& original_msg);
```

as you don't need to return the `std::string` you passed.

II. Yes, at least according to your signature

III. Can see a `node_path` only as a member.

For all your questions, see [C++-FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/).

Answer (score 0):

Your basic assumptions are correct.

```
message_processed.incMsgClass(message_fr_client); //line 4
```

This line is not correct. The function you call returns `msgInfo` which is simply dropped. You should assign it to something. But it is not as it is usually done. You should make it a constructor of msgInfo, like

```
class msgInfo
{
public:
   msgInfo(std::string original_msg);
...
}
```

Then you could call it like this

```
msgInfo message_processed(message_fr_client);
```

That line would create a msgInfo that is already properly initialized.

There is another pattern for creating class instances - static creating function. In your case you could mark `incMsgClass` static and then call it like

```
msgInfo message_processed = msgInfo.incMsgClass(message_fr_client);
```

I seriously doubt you need this pattern here, so I'd advise to move to constructor.

As of other functions, I see no problems there. Just note that all member functions not marked as `const` can modify the object they are called on. So, you don't need to pass this object explicitly. For functions a pointer to the object they are called on is available by name `this`. Also the functions can access all class variables as if these variables are global for normal (non-member) functions.